# NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle gives property list error when calling within NSObject class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created my own localizable string files for a few languages (`XYZLocalizable.strings`) and added them to the bundle. I am able to fetch strings in a UIViewController class using the following line:

`NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"xyz_plugin_title", @"XYZLocalizable", [XYZPluginDelegate bundle], nil);`

But the whole build fails if I add this line in a NSObject class:

```
@interface XYZStringResourceUtil : NSObject

+ (NSString *) getLocalizedString:(NSString *) stringKey;
.
.

@end

@implementation XYZStringResourceUtil

+ (NSString *) getLocalizedString:(NSString *) stringKey {
    NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(stringKey, @"XYZLocalizable", [XYZPluginDelegate bundle], nil);
}
.
.

@end
```

The error that I get is:

```
../DerivedData/XXXXXX/Build/Intermediates.noindex/YYYY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZZZZZ.build/Localization/en.lproj/XYZLocalizable.strings: Unexpected character ÿ at line 1
../DerivedData/XXXXXX/Build/Intermediates.noindex/YYYY.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ZZZZZ.build/Localization/en.lproj/XYZLocalizable.strings: Property List error: Unexpected character ÿ at line 1 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
```

Strangely, the error pops up even if I delete the `.strings` file from the disk. The build only passes when I remove the line from the NSObject class.

Does `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` have any restrictions on where it can be used?

I have already wasted quite a few days trying to find the root cause of this build failure and fix it. I would really appreciate if someone could help fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Unexpected character ÿ at line 1" What's the line? Also, could it be a format or encoding issue?

Comment: Its the first line of the .strings file. I checked the strings file using `plutil -lint`. There are no errors. I tried building by emptying the strings file. It still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround by making thee method, containing the erratic code, a static method instead of a class method.

Though it's still not clear why the class method didn't work.